# Input-depending model on TensorFlow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm working on a TensorFlow model, and I would like to have different logic in the model depending on the input. My question is if it's possible to have a "dispatch" layer in TensorFlow that depending on the input uses one model or another?

**Simplified example:**

Imagine your input has two fields `a: int` and `b: Optional[int]`. This means `b` can be defined or not.

If `b` is not `None` you want to execute some layers, and if it's `None` you want to execute some other layers.

My idea was to have a dispatch layer that depending on the input executes one branch of the model or another one. Something like the architecture in the image below:

[image]

With this architecture, you'll have one only model (which is easier to deploy) with "polymorphism" depending on the input.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I don't know if you can define it in a single model, but why not use 3 models to reach this result?